Onboard keyboard crashing on kubuntu 24.04
Why does onboard keyboard crash every time i open it. Please assist.
Thank you.

Based on the info given here there is no way to offer any help. Details needed. What does on board mean? Is it a laptop keyboard? A software keyboard? Has it ever worked? Did it work and now it does not? What have you changed since it did work? Is a good start.

I have now found a solution:
The presets of onboard are not working anymore with my OS. I could get it back working by changing
“Onboard Settings” → Keyboard → Advanced → Input Options
There I changed “Input event source” from Xinput to GTK.
May be there are now incompatible Xinput calls?

+1. This works for me also in Lubuntu (Noble and Oracular) after an extra tweak (adding zenity to get GTK support).  See details at this link

I solved this by changing the setting 'key-stroke-generator' from auto to 'AT-SPI'.
Under “Onboard Settings” → Keyboard → Advanced → Input Options.
Im running Kubuntu 24.04

Which version (22.04.x LTS or 24.04.x LTS?) and which flavour (Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, ... Xubuntu) are you running?

Im running Kubuntu 24.04
